# Resource error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl2ZP.jpg]

At the beginning of a new project organization, everything is going well. But after writing a bit of code, I encounter a Resource error. Please look at the picture, the red `R`.

Comment: image is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl2ZP.jpg

Comment: What exactly is "R"? It is undefined.

Comment: Please post code and errors in the question itself as text and **not as image**

Comment: error is because your R file is not generating. Clean the project , gradle sync and rebuild your project. then see the logcat

Comment: check ur res folder R file Error come if u have error in res folder or ur layouts

Comment: I'm just added a navigation to my project and suddenly error appeared!

Comment: fixed. Thanks guys :)))

Comment: Fixed spelling, changed title to a more explicit one

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart Android Studio. If that doesnt work import "package.name.R" and if that doesnt work change "AppCompatActivity" to "Activity"